# How to prove $f$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functional-equations

> Suppose $f:U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is  continous  and 
>   $$(x^2+y^4)f(x,y)+(f(x,y))^3=1 \: \text{for all} \: (x,y) \in U. $$  Prove $f$ is $C^\infty$.

This kind of exercise is new to me and I don't really have any idea how to derive that the derivative exist 
infinitely and it's continous.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but that implies $f$ satisfies the functional equations
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{f(x,y)} &= x^2+y^4 + f(x,y)^2\\
f(x,y) &= \frac{1}{x^2+y^4 + f(x,y)^2}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Yeah, we can see that $f(x,y)\ne 0$ otherwise $f$ would not satisfy the equation.

Comment: Idea: Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: Idea: Cardano's formula.

Comment: It gives f(x,y)= (sqrt(3) sqrt(4 a^3 + 27) + 9)^(1/3)/(2^(1/3) 3^(2/3)) - ((2/3)^(1/3) a)/(sqrt(3) sqrt(4 a^3 + 27) + 9)^(1/3) where $a=x^2+y^4$.

Comment: More legible: $$ f(x,y)= \frac{\left(\sqrt3 \sqrt{4 a^3 + 27} + 9\right)^{1/3}}{2^{1/3} 3^{2/3}}-\frac{(2/3)^{1/3} a}{\left(\sqrt3 \sqrt{4 a^3 + 27} +9\right)^{1/3}}$$ where $a=x^2+y^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers really are in the comments to the main question, and are due to Martin Blas Perez and Michael Hoppe. Hence this post is CW.

The function $z=f(x, y)$ satisfies the equation 
$$
(x^2+y^4)z+z^3=1, $$
so it can never vanish. In particular, by the implicit function theorem, $f$ must be $C^1$ and 
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -\frac{2xz}{x^2+y^4+3z^2}, & \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =-\frac{4y^3z}{x^2+y^4+3z^2},
\end{array}
$$
and we remark that the denominators can never vanish. By iterating this process we see that $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

Actually, Micheal even computed an explicit expression for $z$. See his comment to the main question, which I hope he turns into an answer. From that expression it is manifest that $z$ is smooth.

Comment: I'll accept this answer since it addresses Martin and Michael comments. Thanks.